# Use Select query and add its output to text in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have this table

```
Name      Occupation
Maria     Actor
Samantha  Doctor
John      Doctor
Kevin     Professor
```

and i want to count the occurence of professor and output it this way :

> There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.

i know how to count the number of occurences but i don't know how to output the message , can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'There are '|| count(*) ||' '|| occupation
from jobs
group by occupation
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this without `group by` the aid of nested `decode` inside `sum` :

```
select 'There are a total of ' ||  sum(decode(occupation,'&occupation',1,0)) || ' ' || max(occupation) || 's' "Nr. of Prof's" 
     -- enter Professor whenever prompts, besides you may try other occupations as bind variable
  from  Occupations
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96e0c/10)